# Call setter bean from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have searched during a lot of time but I didn't found. I would like to pick an address from jquery address picker that uses gmap api and bind all fields in my beans. Autocompletion and the address field work fine but all other fields doesn't work (null or empty string).

Here is my code :

Javascript :

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        if (document.getElementById("map_form:panel:addresspicker_map")) {
            var addresspickerMap = $("#map_form\\:panel\\:addresspicker_map").addresspicker({
                regionBias: "fr",
                reverseGeocode: true,
                mapOptions: {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 2),
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    reverseGeocode: true
                },
                elements: {
                    map: "#map",
                    lat: "#map_form\\:panel\\:lat",
                    lng: "#map_form\\:panel\\:lng",
                    street_number: '#map_form\\:panel\\:street_number',
                    route: '#map_form\\:panel\\:route',
                    locality: '#map_form\\:panel\\:locality',
                    administrative_area_level_2: '#map_form\\:panel\\:administrative_area_level_2',
                    administrative_area_level_1: '#map_form\\:panel\\:administrative_area_level_1',
                    country: '#map_form\\:panel\\:country',
                    postal_code: '#map_form\\:panel\\:postal_code',
                    type: '#map_form\\:panel\\:type'
                }
            });

            var gmarker = addresspickerMap.addresspicker("marker");
            gmarker.setVisible(true);
            addresspickerMap.addresspicker("updatePosition");

            // Update zoom field
            var map = $("#map_form\\:panel\\:addresspicker_map").addresspicker("map");
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
                $('#map_form\\:panel\\:zoom').val(map.getZoom());
            });
        }

    }
    ;
</script>
```

My JSF Page :

```
<p:tab id="address_site" title="Adresse du site">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Addresse" />
        <p:inputText onfocus="initialize();" id="addresspicker_map" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.address}"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="address_details_site" title="Adresse détaillée">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Street Number" />
        <p:inputText id="street_number" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.street_number}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Route" />
        <p:inputText id="route" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.route}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Postal Code" />
        <p:inputText id="postal_code" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.postal_code}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Locality" />
        <p:inputText id="locality" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.locality}"/>
        <h:outputText value="District" />
        <p:inputText id="administrative_area_level_2" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.district}"/>
        <h:outputText value="State/Province" />
        <p:inputText id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.state_province}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Country" />
        <p:inputText id="country" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.country}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Lat" />
        <p:inputText id="lat" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.latitude}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Lng" />
        <p:inputText id="lng" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.longitude}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Zoom" />
        <p:inputText id="zoom" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.zoom}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Type" />
        <h:inputText id="type" disabled="true" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.type}"/>
        <h:outputText value="Map" />
        <div id="map"></div>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="confirmation_site" title="Confirmation">
    <h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" actionListener="#{contratsController.addSite}" value="Ajouter" />
</p:tab>
```

When I push commandButton, **contratsController.currentSiteCreate.address** is well filled but all others fields is null or empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons JSF and PrimeFaces do not process values when inputs are `disabled="true"` or `readonly="true"`.

So in order to do your scenario I would suggest you use JSF hidden field for every disabled input, this way your hidden fields will hold the values, while your inputs will be just for display.
Your page would be like this:

```
 <h:outputText value="Street Number" />
 <p:inputText id="street_number" disabled="true" value=""/>
 <h:inputHidden id="street_number_hidden" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.street_number}" />

 <h:outputText value="Route" />
 <p:inputText id="route" disabled="true" value=""/>
 <h:inputHidden id="route_hidden" value="#{contratsController.currentSiteCreate.route}"/>

 ...
```